# How to have more then one java file in cordova plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have plugin.xml file that look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin id="pl.jcubic.leash.service" version="1.0.0"
        xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0">
  <name>Exec</name>
  <description>Apache Cordova Leash shell service plugin</description>
  <license>Apache 2.0</license>
  <keywords>cordova,exec,runtime,process,shell,command</keywords>
  <js-module name="service" src="www/service.js">
    <clobbers target="service"/>
  </js-module>
  <platform name="android">
    <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
      <feature name="Service">
        <param name="android-package" value="pl.jcubic.leash.Service" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
      </feature>
    </config-file>
    <source-file src="src/pl/jcubic/leash/Service.java"
                 target-dir="src/pl/jcubic/leash/Service" />
  </platform>
</plugin>
```

my plugin is in Service.java file but now I want to create super class and put some logic there so my Service.java file look like this:

```
package pl.jcubic.leash;

public class Service extends ReflectService {

    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
        // your init code here
    }

    public String echo(String input) {
        if (input.equals("ping")) {
            return "pong";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

and ReflectService.java look like this:

```
package pl.jcubic.leash;

public class ReflectService extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
    }
   ...
}
```

but when I've add the plugin and run cordova run android I've got this error:

```
/home/kuba/projects/jcubic/leash/leash/platforms/android/src/pl/jcubic/leash/Service/Service.java:22: error: cannot find symbol                                                      
public class Service extends ReflectService {
                             ^
  symbol: class ReflectService
/home/kuba/projects/jcubic/leash/leash/platforms/android/src/pl/jcubic/leash/Service/Service.java:25: error: cannot find symbol                                                      
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
        ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class Service
2 errors
```

How can I import class from the same package in android/cordova plugin? When I've installed the plugin the ReflectService.java file is there. Do I need to put more then one source-file in xml file? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I need to do is to put another source-file into xml file:

```
<source-file src="src/pl/jcubic/leash/Service.java"
             target-dir="src/pl/jcubic/leash/Service" />
<source-file src="src/pl/jcubic/leash/ReflectService.java"
             target-dir="src/pl/jcubic/leash/Service" />
```

Comment: Hmmm.  That works but does not seem ideal for plugins with multiple files.  Have you found an alternate approach that supports wildcards?

Comment: @EJK This is from 2017, I didn't use Cordova in years. I can assure you that if I would have better solution I would update the answer.

Comment: @EJK note that you don't need to write this by hand you can generate this file based on wildcards.